# LazyColumn how to fit in screen with other Composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
fun   ShowScreen(viewModel: UseListViewModel){
    Column() {
        ShowList(viewModel = viewModel)
        Buttons(viewModel)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ShowList(viewModel: UseListViewModel) {

    LazyColumn() {
        items(viewModel.itemListMutableState.value?: emptyList()){
            ShowItem(it,viewModel)
        }
    }

}
@Composable
private fun ShowItem(item: IBaseDataModel, viewModel: UseListViewModel) {
    Row (horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,verticalAlignment= Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(AppConstants.itemHolderBackgroundColor(item.state)))
            .clickable { viewModel.selectItem(item) }

            .fillMaxWidth()
    ){
        Text(text = item.idString)
        Text(text = item.date1String)
        Checkbox(checked = item.isSelected,onCheckedChange = { viewModel.setIsSelectedItem(item,it)})
        Button(onClick = {viewModel.deleteItem(item)}) {
            Text(text = "delete")
        }
    }


}
@Composable
private fun Buttons(viewModel: UseListViewModel){
    Row (verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom,modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly){
        Button(onClick = {viewModel.refreshClick()}) {
            Text(text = "refresh")
        }
        Button(onClick = {viewModel.addClick()}) {
            Text(text = "add")
        }
        val a=if(viewModel.itemListMutableState.value!=null) viewModel.buttonsViewViewModel.buttonNext.visibility else 8

        if(a==0){
            Button(onClick = {viewModel.nextStateClick()}) {
                Text(text = "next")
            }
        }


    }

}
```

when the list items fill the screen the buttons disapear ..
how to keep the Buttons on screen bottom ?

Many apps need to display collections of items. This document explains how you can efficiently do this in Jetpack Compose.

If you know that your use case does not require any scrolling, you may wish to use a simple Column or Row (depending on the direction), and emit each item’s content by iterating over a list like so:

Answer (score 3):

Use `weight()` method like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ShowScreen(viewModel: UseListViewModel) {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { // <-- new
        ShowList(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), // <-- new
            viewModel = viewModel
        )
        Buttons(viewModel)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ShowList(
    modifier: Modifier, // <-- new
    viewModel: UseListViewModel
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier) { // <-- new
        items(viewModel.itemListMutableState.value ?: emptyList()) {
            ShowItem(it, viewModel)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ShowItem(item: IBaseDataModel, viewModel: UseListViewModel) {
    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(AppConstants.itemHolderBackgroundColor(item.state)))
            .clickable { viewModel.selectItem(item) }
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(text = item.idString)
        Text(text = item.date1String)
        Checkbox(
            checked = item.isSelected,
            onCheckedChange = { viewModel.setIsSelectedItem(item, it) })
        Button(onClick = { viewModel.deleteItem(item) }) {
            Text(text = "delete")
        }
    }


}

@Composable
private fun Buttons(viewModel: UseListViewModel) {
    Row(
//        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom, // remove this
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        Button(onClick = { viewModel.refreshClick() }) {
            Text(text = "refresh")
        }
        Button(onClick = { viewModel.addClick() }) {
            Text(text = "add")
        }
        val a =
            if (viewModel.itemListMutableState.value != null) viewModel.buttonsViewViewModel.buttonNext.visibility else 8

        if (a == 0) {
            Button(onClick = { viewModel.nextStateClick() }) {
                Text(text = "next")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it helps then please mark this as an accepted answer and give an upvote. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `Column` and use just one `LazyColumn` for the `ShowScreen`.
`ShowList` can now be an extension function for `LazyListScope`, this will allow calling `items` of parent `LazyColumn` directly within the `ShowList` function.

```
@Composable
fun ShowScreen(viewModel: UseListViewModel){
    LazyColumn {
        ShowList(viewModel)
        item { 
            Buttons(viewModel)
        }
    }
}

private fun LazyListScope.ShowList(viewModel: UseListViewModel) {
    items(viewModel.itemListMutableState.value?: emptyList()){
        ShowItem(it,viewModel)
    }
}
```

Note that ShowList is not a `@Composable` function now.